# Magento 1.9 product page show 404 error not found

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, category-products

i removed categories URL from product URL now when i access product which is assign to multiple categories generate 404 error but products which assign to only category working fine any help ?

Comment: Did you reindex after applying that change?

Comment: yes i did but issue is stile there

Comment: Have you checked in admin>Url Rewrite Management section?

Comment: Check answers & give feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have reindexed (**catalog url** mainly), cleared cache & error persists the most probable is you have something wrong in **core_url_rewrite** database table

If you have not registered any manual url redirect there you can safely `truncate` that table with the database manager you use, as reindex process will fill it back

Be sure to check Magento log files (**var/log** folder) also, as it is probable reindex process is throwing some errors (duplicate urls or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which ended up being a caching issue in my browser.  When I removed my site's cookies and cache, the page showed up right away.